# Fastest way to sort a column(datetime) in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I need to sort a dataframe based on a column which contains datetime, but its taking too much time. Appx 7 * 10^7 rows. 
P.S. I have tried sort_values() function.

Comment: How long is "too much time"? If you only need to do it once, 8 hours (i.e., one night of sleep) is not long.

Comment: Often, sorting a dataframe is only needed for output. Without context, it's hard to say, but you may not need to sort your dataframe in the first place.

Comment: @0 0 I am using merge_asof  for which i need to sort dataframe first

Comment: I am not sure of your problem. But can you read your data to pandas in sorted form? Maybe it will be faster in database like postgres? Have you look for other methods of optimizing? What do you have in index?

Comment: @404pio I am still looking for optimising methods, alsoi don't have anything in index